# Repercussion of loading packages within a function instead of class

Tags: ruby, function, class, rubygems

Let's say I want use a library called 'toad'.

I can do (in Ruby pseudo-code):

```
require 'toad'

Class MyClass
 def do_stuff
   Toad.do_toad_stuff
 end
...
end
```

But I can also do

```
...
 def do_stuff
   require 'toad'
   Toad.do_toad_stuff
 end
...
```

Let's say toad is a rather small library. Does it (really) matter where I do it? If it matters, let's say this function gets called a few times per user visit to my web application.

I guess I'm ultimately curious if any optimization happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the question of how often the `do_stuff` will be called. If just a few times, then use the `require` inside it, otherwise require just once.

It easy to test it:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'json' # require any library, doesn't matter

n = 1_000_000

def foo_with_require
  require 'json'
  2 + 2
end

def foo_without_require
  2 + 2
end

Benchmark.bm(20) do |benchmark|
  benchmark.report('require each time', 20) do
    n.times { foo_with_require }
  end
  benchmark.report('require once') do
    n.times { foo_without_require }
  end
end
```

The results are the following:

```
                           user     system      total        real
require each time      2.260000   0.010000   2.270000 (  2.273471)
require once           0.080000   0.010000   0.090000 (  0.079403)
```

So requiring just once is about 30 times faster, when the function body is as simple as `2 + 2`, but if your function does anything more meaningful, the difference will be negligible.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points:

1. Putting `require 'toad'` within a method doesn't change the fact that it will load constants (e.g. modules) and globals into the (global) scope of the running program.
2. `require` does remember the files it has already loaded (see `$LOADED_FEATURES`) and will only load a unique file path once.
3. To defer requiring a file until it's necessary to do so, you can use `autoload` (which was to be deprecated at one point because of thread-safety, but that's been addressed and it's still part of Kernel), as follows:

   ```
   class MyClass
     autoload :Toad, 'toad'
     ...
   end
   ```